# How to validate mutiple data (stored as array) in Laravel Eloquent ORM?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form the takes multiple input from the user. It then stores the input inside an array and pass it to laravel eloquent ORM

```
...
var data = {
    act_code:       act_code,
    organization:   organization,
    status:         status,
    device_code:    device_code,
    project:        project,
    act_date:       act_date
}
formdata.push(data);

$http.post('./api/activity', {
    formdata
})...
```

formdata will now be passed to the laravel controller:

```
public function store()
{   
     // validate
     $validator = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
         'formdata.*.act_code'          => 'required|unique:tsqgeointel_activation,act_code',
         'formdata.*.organization'      => 'required',
         'formdata.*.status'                => 'required|boolean',
         'formdata.*.project'               => 'required',
         'formdata.*.act_date'          => 'required'
     ]);

     if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(array(
            'success'   => false,
            'status'    => $validator->messages()
            ));
     } else {
        $activity = ActCode::insert(Request::all());
        return response()->json(array(
            'success'   => true,
            'activity'  => $activity,
            'status'    => $validator->messages()
            ));
    }
}
```

this is what the formdata looks like with the example on the laravel controller:

```
array (
  'formdata' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'act_code' => 'sample001',
      'organization' => 'sampleorg',
      'status' => false,
      'device_code' => 0,
      'project' => 'sampleproj',
      'act_date' => '2016-11-23 06:38:11',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'act_code' => 'sample002',
      'organization' => 'sampleorg',
      'status' => false,
      'device_code' => 0,
      'project' => 'sampleproj',
      'act_date' => '2016-11-23 06:38:11',
    ),
  ),
)
```

why does the validation does not pass? validation message is:

```
app.js:179 formdata.*.act_code: The formdata.*.act code field is required.
app.js:179 formdata.*.organization: The formdata.*.organization field is required.
app.js:179 formdata.*.status: The formdata.*.status field is required.
app.js:179 formdata.*.project: The formdata.*.project field is required.
app.js:179 formdata.*.act_date: The formdata.*.act date field is required.
```

Comment: var_dump the Request::all()

Comment: why the server have the formdata index?